# How can i access the Vtiger Database object?

Tags: crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

I am writing a php script to import some data into my custom module, basically i will run a cron job periodically to copy some data from another table to populate my custom module fields.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question exactly. Would you please provide more detail.

Comment: Although i mentioned in the title but still i think i should have explained in the detail section. Sorry about that, but you handled it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **PearDatabase.php** class to get database access and functions related to the DB operations.

**Example:**

```
<?php
include_once 'include/database/PearDatabase.php';
$db = PearDatabase::getInstance();
$result = $db->pquery("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'leads'", array());
echo $db->num_rows($result);
print_r($result);
echo "<br>Test Done <br>";


//Using $db object you can access other DB related methods defined in that class.
//Include the file in your module in any file where you want DB operation.
// But I would recommend, use inside your main module class or model controller class.
?>
```

Put this PHP script into your root directory and run directly this file using your browser. So you will get some idea and you can able to use inside your module because all module loads from index.php file (root directory).

Comment: Thank you! i exactly needed this.